# Unity. Getting data from input fields for script then changing text object

Tags: c#

Using c# and unity4 and unity 5

So i have looked for ages and couldnt find anything to specifically solve my issue.

Specifically what im trying to do is add input fields via editor and then write a script that can call the data that is then entered for functions lets say 2 numbers and then i wanna be able to hit a button and have a text object change its text and show the result.

I have tried all sorts but so far best bet is guilayout in script but that way makes it much harder to set ui up how i want it.

Could someone please give me a couple ways to go about doing this? I just cant get script and inpitfields to communicate.

Comment: Im trying to grab the TextComponent of the input field to use in script

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is little confusing, u can go through this,
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-InputField.html
you will get to know about how to handle input field. use On edit end from the inspector to work with the value from input field. use a UI text and assign the value on the text field like 
TextBox.text = yourValue.toString();